# Separate observable values by specific amount of time in RxJS

Tags: javascript, system.reactive, rxjs

What would be the most idiomatic way to yield values of an Observable by a specific amount of time? For example, let's say I have an Observable created from a big Array and I want to yield a value every 2 seconds. Is a combination of `interval` and `selectMany` the best way?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For your specific example, the idea is to map each value from the array to an observable that will yield its result after a delay, then concatenate the resulting stream of observables:

```
var delayedStream = Rx.Observable
    .fromArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    .map(function (value) { return Rx.Observable.return(value).delay(2000); })
    .concatAll();
```

Other examples might indeed make use of `timer` or `interval`.  It just depends.

For example, if your array is really really big, then the above will cause a fair amount of memory pressure (because it is creating `N` observables for a really large `N`).  Here is an alternative that uses `interval` to lazily walk the array:

```
var delayedStream = Rx.Observable
    .interval(2000)
    .take(reallyBigArray.length) // end the observable after it pulses N times
    .map(function (i) { return reallyBigArray[i]; });
```

This one will yield the next value from the array every 2 seconds until it has iterated over the entire array.

Answer (score 26):

I think that using zip produce better and more readable code, still using just 3 observables.

```
var items = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

Rx.Observable.zip(
  Rx.Observable.fromArray(items),
  Rx.Observable.timer(2000, 2000),  
  function(item, i) { return item;}
)
```

Comment: maybe a ```take(items.length)``` operator should be added to  the timer to allow the obervable to ever complete

Comment: `take(items.length)` is completely useless. Stream itself is immutable object, and take (or any other operation) is not affecting source observable but derives a new object from it.

Which means your proposal creates just 4 observabbles instead of 3.
Completion of `zip` is managed by source array and all memory cleanup is then up to RxJS

Comment: Careful - I think this may not work in most practical cases / where the first observable (items) pushes items at unpredictable times. Imagine eg items is delayed by 10 seconds. By the time it produces its items, timer has already ticked 5 times, so all items would be immediately pushed out, and not spaced out by 2 seconds each

Comment: @Bogey you are right, this only separate arrays or 'fast' observables

Answer (score 11):

For RxJS v6 getting the next one with a delay of 2 seconds.

**Example 1.** concatMap:

```
import {of} from 'rxjs';
import {concatMap, delay} from 'rxjs/operators';

of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
  .pipe(
    concatMap(x => of(x)
      .pipe(
        delay(2000))
    )
  )
  .subscribe({
    next(value) {
      console.log(value);
    }
  });
```

**Example 2.** map + concatAll:

```
import {of} from 'rxjs';
import {concatAll, delay, map} from 'rxjs/operators';

of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
  .pipe(
    map(x => of(x)
      .pipe(
        delay(2000))
    ),
    concatAll()
  )
  .subscribe({
    next(value) {
      console.log(value);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 9):

While Brandon's answer gets the gist of the idea, here's a version which yields the first item immediately, then puts time between the following items.

```
var delay = Rx.Observable.empty().delay(2000);

var items = Rx.Observable.fromArray([1,2,3,4,5])
  .map(function (x) {
    return Rx.Observable.return(x).concat(delay); // put some time after the item
  })
  .concatAll();
```

Updated for newer RxJS:

```
var delay = Rx.Observable.empty().delay(2000);

var items = Rx.Observable.fromArray([1,2,3,4,5])
  .concatMap(function (x) {
    return Rx.Observable.of(x).concat(delay); // put some time after the item
  });
```

Comment: Note `return` is now `of` : https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md

Comment: This can now be `concatMap` (guessing concatMap is newer than 2014?). This just queues them all together (otherwise they are all emitted together with a delay following)

Comment: eg. `.concatMap(x => Observable.of(x).concat(Observable.empty().delay(5000)))`

Comment: Simon, feel free to update the answer with the new naming conventions and simplifications.

Comment: Thx. This was the best solution for me. I want to show notifications (like toast notifications) instantly, but delay the 2nd notification if two arrive at once :-)

Answer (score 6):

For RxJS 5:

```
Rx.Observable.from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
  .zip(Rx.Observable.timer(0, 2000), x => x)
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Answer (score 4):

Agree that zip is a clean approach. Here is a reusable function to generate an interval stream for an array:

```
function yieldByInterval(items, time) {
  return Rx.Observable.from(items).zip(
    Rx.Observable.interval(time),
    function(item, index) { return item; }
  );
}

// test
yieldByInterval(['A', 'B', 'C'], 2000)
  .subscribe(console.log.bind(console));
```

This builds on [farincz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31855054/1480391), but is slightly shorter by using `.zip` as an instance method.

Also, I used `Rx.Observable.from()` because `Rx.Observable.fromArray()` is [deprecated](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/fromarray.md).

Answer (score 4):

Since this wasn't mentioned, I think [`concatMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html) combined with [`delay`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/delay.html) is pretty readable.

```
Rx.Observable.fromArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    .concatMap(x => Rx.Observable.of(x).delay(1000));
```

See https://codepen.io/jmendes/pen/EwaPzw

Answer (score 1):

A simple one-liner:

```
const delayMs = 2000
from([1, 2, 3]).pipe(concatMap(x => of(x).pipe(delay(delayMs)))).subscribe(item => {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on the zip solutions by farincz and user3587412, here is how it works in RxJS v6

```
const { zip, from, timer } = require("rxjs")
const { map } = require("rxjs/operators")

const input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const delay = 2000

zip(
    from(input),
    timer(0, delay)
).pipe(
    map(([ delayedInput, _timer ]) => delayedInput) // throw away timer index
).subscribe(
    console.log
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//create a custom operator
const delayEach=(millis)=>(o)=>o.pipe(concatMap((x)=>of(x).pipe(delay(millis))))



of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
  .pipe(delayEach(1000))
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

RxJs 6 code that emits the first item immediately and delays the remaining items:

```
import { of, EMPTY, concat } from "rxjs";
import { concatMap, delay } from "rxjs/operators";

const delayed$ = EMPTY.pipe(delay(1000));

console.log("start");
of(1, 2, 3, 4)
  .pipe(concatMap(v => concat(of(v), delayed$)))
  .subscribe({
    next: console.log
  });
```

[Full Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-delay-after-first?file=index.ts)

idea:

- for each item we create an observable (using `concat`) that will output the item immediately (`of(v)`) and then emit an `EMPTY` observable after the delay
- since we use `concatMap` all emitted observables will be emitted in the correct order