# Rate limiting/Sleeping/Delaying nodejs without busy waiting

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am looking to set a delay in making http requests to avoid going over the rate limit of the external server.

```
users.forEach(async function(user) {
    await rate_check()
    make_http_request()
})
```

I need help with implementing the rate_check function in a way that would avoid busy waiting. At the moment, I am busy waiting as follows

```
async function rate_check() {
    if(rate_counter < rate_limit)
        rate_counter += 1
    else {
        // Busy wait
        while(new Date() - rate_0_time < 1000) {}
        rate_counter = 1
        time_delta = new Date() - rate_0_time
        rate_1_time = new Date()
    }
}
```

`await new Promise(resolve => { setTimeout(resolve, 2000)})` does not work as it would only cause rate_check to sleep, but the anonymous function would continue to make requests.

Any rate checking code must be done in the rate_check function and not in the function where the http request happens as requests happen across multiple async functions and they are making requests to the same server.

I am open to any other suggestions as well as refactoring as long as it avoids nesting callbacks or third-party dependency

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lodash `throttle` function https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#throttle to wrap around your side effect function. It will at most call it once per interval and memoize the last returned result (so you may want to return data instead of a stateful object such as an http body).

Comment: It seems that throttle might not be what is desired for cases like this, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37575282/908677