# Why is Observable.delay() not respected?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have a simple HTTP call:

```
  getContributors(pageNumber): Observable<any> {
    const url = `${this.apiBaseUrl}/orgs/angular/public_members?&page=${pageNumber}`;
    const requestOptions = this.getRequestOptions();

    return this.http.get(url, requestOptions);
  }
```

the call is made within a `ngrx effect`.

```
...
return this.contributorsService.getContributors(payload.pageNumber)
        .delay(new Date(Date.now() + Math.random() * 500))
        ... // mergeMap etc. here
```

However, while the HTTP call returns an **array** of multiple values, they're **in any case** emitted **all at once**.

Am I misunderstanding the purpose of `delay()` operator (and in this case, how do I achieve the expected result?) or am I using it the wrong way?

Note: I imported the augmentation `import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';`

**UPDATE**: to clarify, the **expected result** is: I want the array to be split and each single value within the array to be emitted separately at a given (constant) time

**UPDATE 2**: so, the array is **actually split** by

```
 .flatMap(data => Observable.from(data))
```

In fact, If

```
 .do(value => console.log(value))
```

each value is printed **individually**.

However, if instead of .do(....)

I put

```
.delay(3000)
.do(() => console.log(new Date())
```

I can see the delay is not respected **at all** (except for the fact it actually awaits 3000 to emit **all** the values **in a sequence with no delay** - in a row, i.e. multiple console.logs)

Comment: what exactly is your expected result? delay takes your value and... delays it for however long, if your value is an array, then it doesn't split the array into a stream of values or anything like that, it delays the entire single value.

Comment: @bryan60 exactly, I want the array to be split and each single value within the array to be emitted separately at a given (constant) time

Comment: please update your question with the expected result, writing up an answer

Comment: @bryan60 done. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, so the thing about arrays in observable streams, is they're just like any other single value in a stream. Your http call returns an array value, so it returns the entire array as a single value which goes all at once. If you want to split an array into multiple values, you can certainly do that, but you need to tell rxjs to do so, my preferred method is to use flatMap from like this:

```
.flatMap(arrVal => Observable.from(arrVal))
```

This operation will flatten your array value into an observable stream of values, so you could use it like this:

```
return this.contributorsService.getContributors(payload.pageNumber)
    .flatMap(data => Observable.from(data))
    .delay(Math.random() * 500) // you should just feed a ms value to delay if you want constant time interval, date parameters mean delay till that date, so they'll all just flow through at that date
```

However, the above won't work because delay shifts the entire stream by the time, rather than each item, so to accomplish a flattening and separating, we need to get a little more explicit, drawing from this answer: [Separate observable values by specific amount of time in RxJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21661391/separate-observable-values-by-specific-amount-of-time-in-rxjs)

```
return this.contributorsService.getContributors(payload.pageNumber)
           .switchMap(data => Observable.interval(Math.random() * 500)
                                        .take(data.length)
                                        .map(i => data[i]))
```

This way we manually flatten the array at an evenly spaced interval.

This version will also work and may feel slightly cleaner:

```
return this.contributorsService.getContributors(payload.pageNumber)
           .flatMap(data => Observable.from(data))
           .zip(Observable.interval(Math.random() * 500), (d,i) => d)
```

This just uses the zip operator to zip each item with an observable that emits on an interval.

Now you should see your desired behavior of each array item coming through one at a time at a constant interval.  But, if you're using the http service, you probably need to call .json() on your response to get the value as an array, like this:

```
return this.http.get(url, requestOptions).map(res => res.json());
```

Comment: thanks. seems to work. let me look into it and then I'll accept the answer

Comment: actually, it doesn't seem to work. I'll update my question with details @bryan60

Comment: it's because you're using a Date as an input to delay, check my comment on why you shouldn't do that and should jsut use ms, the .now() is only evaluated once, not for every item, you need a constant time, there is no reason at all for you to use a date input.

Comment: sorry, I missed that. Nonetheless even if for example I pass 3000 (see updated question), the behavior doesn't change (except for the fact it actually awaits 3000 to emit ALL THE values and SEPARATELY)

Comment: yea i just read the docs on delay operator, it seems to shift the entire stream rather than each item. I will change my answer.

Comment: Thanks. a bit late now, will try it tomorrow ;) Thanks for the effort!

Comment: While both solutions (including Richard's one)  are interesting, I'll accept it as I like the .zip approach (more intuitive). Worth noticing it didn't work without first updating rxjs to the latest version

Answer (score 2):

You can use `delay()` by flatMap'ing a second time,

```
return this.contributorsService.getContributors(payload.pageNumber)
  .flatMap(x => x)                                            // to single values
  .flatMap(x => Observable.of(x).delay(Math.random() * 500))  // apply delay
```

```js
const Observable = Rx.Observable

Observable.of([1,2,3])
  .flatMap(x => x)
  .flatMap(x => Observable.of(x).delay(Math.random() * 500))
  .subscribe(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.3/Rx.js"></script>
```