# Observable and how to control results pace

Tags: rxjs, observable, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I am looking for an operator that would help me pace the results emitted from an observable, it would look like this :

```
[--A-BC--D-E----------------]
[--A----B----C----D----E----]
```

I tried AuditTime() but it does not replay the results that was emitted between intervals, it does something like this :

```
[--A-BC--D-E----------------]
[--A----C----E--------------]
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: May I ask, is the Source Observable long-lived, i.e. does it emit again some time after the last emission went through the pipe?

Comment: Is this possible: [--A-BC--D-E--------------F-] ?

Comment: Yes. Maybe my knowledge of Observable/Observer is not good enough ... maybe it's something you should do on the observer side...

Comment: Okay, no this looks like a task for pipes. I just can't find anything built-in ;)

Comment: Yes, can't find anything that would replay slowly all values emitted since the observer subscribed to it.

Comment: You can take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21661391/separate-observable-values-by-specific-amount-of-time-in-rxjs 

But I'm afraid that would cause problems with long-lived observables as the zip operator will also queue the timer emissions.

Comment: Look at Answer 2

Comment: @leonsaysHi so you want to make an equal delay between two emissions

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do what you need:

```
const e1 =  cold('--A-BC--D-E----------------|');
const expected = '--A----B----C----D----E----|';

const source = e1.pipe(
  concatMap(val => of(false).pipe(
    delay(5, scheduler),
    takeWhile(Boolean),
    startWith(val),
  )),
);

expectObservable(source).toBe(expected);
```

The trick here is that I'm using `concatMap` to always wait until the previous Observable completes. The inner Observable emits the value and then postpones its own completion and thus `concatMap` enforces the delay between two emissions.

See live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs6-test-scheduler?file=index.ts